# Joomla! log in error on http vs http://www

Tags: joomla

I've got a client with a bizarre Joomla/CiviCRM issue.

When the client is logged in at http://www.site.com, when they perform certain CiviCRM actions, they are redirected to http://site.com, which they are not logged in at. However, when they log in a second time at http://site.com they are able to function normally. However, if they log out at http://site.com, they are still logged in at http://www.site.com

Confused? The kicker is that I updated the CiviCRM baseurl to be http://www.site.com. But even clearing caches hasn't helped that bleed through.

What is happening here?

1. Is the http://www vs http:// login distinction a Joomla! only one?
2. Is there anything else I need to do to clear CiviCRM's caches regarding stored http://site.com addresses?
3. I deleted civicrm_cache session entries, but they seemingly aren't being regenerated. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Consider picking either `www.site.com` or `site.com` as the canonical domain. Then:

- Setup an httpd redirect (in Apache or nginx) from one domain to the other domain.
- Ensure that the configuration files (e.g. both of Joomla's `civicrm.settings.php` files) and "Resource URLs" consistently point to the same domain.

(Alternatively, you could dig further into how the URL settings work, but *usually*, when you consider SEO and marketing consistency, it's higher-value to use the same domain consistently.)

Comment: Tim is spot on. I always add a redirect to my sites to redirect to https://www.site.com (unless we are specifically using a certain subdomain). This issue also occurs when dealing with http vs https, so you can kill multiple birds with one redirect rule.

Comment: FWIW ... if you use Akeeba's Admin Tools Pro (well worth the cost), the .htaccess, NginX Configuration and web.config Maker module can create the proper settings to do this without much fuss.